# ¿Cómo puedo devolver 3 arrays con foreach de laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
     <?php
          $productos = array
                    (
                    $produ_nom,
                    $produ_pre,
                    $produ_can
                    );
          ?>
          @foreach($productos as $pro)
            {
            <tr>
              <td class="service">Venta</td>
              <td class="desc">{{$pro[0]}}</td>
              <td class="unit">{{$pro[1]}}</td>
              <td class="qty">{{$pro[2]}}</td>
              <td class="total">{{$pro[3]}}</td>
            </tr>
            }
        @endforeach
```

pero al devolver el código me aparece lo de la imagen.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me devuelva los datos en diferente orden? ya que si le coloco 2 índices al array me devuelve un caracter nada mas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las variables $produ_nom,$produ_pre,$produ_can, que contienen?

Comment: Nombre del producto, precio y cantidad, pero vienen de unos array en el controlador.